# How Do I Remove a text Parenthesis Using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, element

I have some auto-generated text that includes non-ascii encoded parentheses.  For example:

```
<div> Some text (these are the non-ascii encoded parenthesis).
<div>
```

I want to get rid of the parenthesis.  I have the following, which I use elsewhere to clean out some html elements, but I can't get similar to work to remove actual text:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".block").find("p").remove()});
```

I've found a few ideas around, but they deal with normal text.  Getting rid of a parenthesis is a challenge, as I'm not sure how to code the parenthesis so that jQuery understands it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the parentheses themselves, or everything they contain as well?

Comment: I'm just looking to ditch the parentheses, but it looks like Andy's answer below includes code to nix everything in between also.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should do the replacing/cleaning with vanilla Javascript. Something like

```
$('div').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
});
```

will do it. Notice, this would query for all `<div>` nodes on the entire side, you want to be more specific on the selector.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2gHh2/

If you'd like to remove the parenthesis and everything in between, you'd simply have to change the regular expression to `/\(.*?\)/g`.

Comment: That works great if the entire div is text, but the div has other elements in it.  These are getting obliterated.  For example, on your fiddle site, add an <a> element inside the div... it gets ignored, by which I mean it does not get interpreted by the browser and shown as a link.

Comment: @user624385: I've updated the jsfiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/2gHh2/2/. That should do the job generically for any childnodes within a parentnode too.

Comment: Yes!  Your answer at jsfiddle.net/2gHh2/2 is perfect!  Thank you very much, sir!  I've paypal'd you $5 for a coffee.  Much obliged.

Comment: @user624385: oh nice, thanks dude. (I'm dreaming of every answer got rewarded by 5 bucks.... hehe)

Comment: the removal of bits between the parenthesis helped a ton as well! thanks jAndy :)