# How to style parentheses and the text inbetween them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, styling, parentheses

I have a line of text:

```html
<h1 class="productName">Product Name (Blue)</h1>
```

and I wish to style the parentheses and the text inbetween - ideally placing a `span` around them.

I have tried adapting the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7189635), but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have this HTML:

```
<div id="test">Product name (colour)</div>
```

You can use this javscript to add the span as requested:

```
var o = document.getElementById("test")
o.innerHTML = o.innerHTML.replace(/\([^\)]*\)/, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
```

And, then set CSS for the class to control the formatting.

If you want to replace more than one, then you would have to add the g flag and change the regex slightly for min match instead of max match to this:

```
var o = document.getElementById("test")
o.innerHTML = o.innerHTML.replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');.
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NyaZ2/.

OK, now that you've included the HTML, you can do it using jQuery like this:

```
var o = $(".productName");
o.html(o.html().replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'));
```

Comment: Actually, the text is wrapped with an h1 class... is there a getElementByclass or equivilant?

Comment: Please add sample HTML to your question.  It's too hard to guess what you mean.  Using jQuery, there are zillions of possible selectors we could use to zero in on the right text, but we have to see all the relevant HTML around and above it to know what to use.

Comment: Sorry jfriend00 :( - I have edited the question to show the markup

Comment: I added a new version to my answer that shows how you could do it with your HTML using jQuery.  And, the code would process all tags with `class="productName"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- load jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h1').each(function(){
        var splitChar = '(';
        var tmp = $(this).text().split(splitChar);
        if (tmp.length == 2) {
            $(this).html(tmp[0] + '<span>(' + tmp[1] + '</span>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style> span { color: #c00; } </style>
<body>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
        <h1>Product name (colour)</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: I would even say it is the only solution from offered on this page, that really works flawlessly. The one marked as **answer** would turn every `Parameter 1 (value 1)`, `Parameter 2 (value 2)`, `Parameter 3 (value 3)` into `Parameter 1 (value 1)` or into anything that appears first on the page and suits the rules.